# Search message extension issue in a group chat

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

We have a Microsoft Teams message extension app. If I search in a group chat and select one item in the result the chat input disappears and the "New conversation" button is shown again. This was working correctly earlier when there was no "New conversation" button in group chats only the chat input directly. This was working in earlier version of Teams, when there was no "New conversation" button.
This happens only if the result ThumbnailCards have "invoke" Tap CardAction. If I remove the "invoke" Tap CardAction, then the selected item in the result is inserted into the chat input correctly.

In private chat it is working correctly with the "invoke" Tap CardAction.

This is the ThumbnailCard for each search result item:

```
        ...    
        var card = new ThumbnailCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Text = cardContent,
            Images = new System.Collections.Generic.List<CardImage> { new CardImage(iconUrl) },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, downloadText, null, itemLink, downloadText, itemLink) },
            Tap = new CardAction
            {
                Type = "invoke",
                Value = new JObject
                {
                    ["Id"] = GetItemPermanentId(item["Link"].ToString()),
                    ["Title"] = title,
                    ["Text"] = cardContent,
                    ["IconUrl"] = iconUrl,
                    ["DownloadText"] = downloadText,
                    ["DownloadLink"] = itemLink
                }
            }
        };

        var attachment = card
            .ToAttachment()
            .ToMessagingExtensionAttachment();
  
        return attachment;
        ...
```

The OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync method is called correctly after I click on a result, but as described above, the chat input disappears and the "New conversation" button is shown again.

Target framework: .NET Core 2.1,
AdaptiveCards: 2.1.0,
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure: 4.9.2,
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core: 4.7.0.

Is this a Microsoft Teams bug or I need to change something on the code?

Comment: This Bug is resolved now, You can check and let us know if you are still facing this issue

Comment: Tested and is working now correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams update fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to repro the issue at our end raised a bug. We don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed.